# Error: 0xc0000098 when dual booting Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have been wanting to install Ubuntu on my laptop for some time now, but every time I try I get this message when I boot after installing Ubuntu:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

  Status: 0xc0000098

  Info: The selected item could not be initialized, because the program is missing or is damaged.
```

I can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue and then I get a boot choice between Ubuntu and Windows 7, but if I choose Ubuntu I get the same message as above. If I launch Windows 7, there are no problems and my OS runs as normal. Why can't I boot Ubuntu, and how do I fix this?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to add Ubuntu to the working Windows 7 system? IE: what method are you using to create the dual-boot?  Aside form pressing enter when you get the message, what steps have you taken in attempting to rectify your problem (to avoid us suggesting things you've already tried)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is quite common. The point is that your MBR (or equivalent for UEFI) has been corrupted in the process. Your first line of defense is the installation of Boot-Repair, a utility available in Ubuntu that addrresses exactly this sort of problems. You may want to try it. You find the instructions to download it [on a Ubuntu Manpage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). The same page also contains instructions to run it. Its first attempt is totally automatic and, in my experience solves most of the problems.

Should this fail, the output with the details of the failure would be most helpful.

Comment: The main problem is that I can't under any circumstance actaully launch ubuntu. I have now tried a USB boot from the ISO file but when I boot it I only get a console up with no GUI. Before the console I get this text saying:
"SYSLINUX 4.04 EDD 2011-04-18 Copyright (C) 1994-2011 H. Peter Anvin et al
ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot:_"